# lodash searchIndex on reverse sorted list

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a sorted array as follows:

```
var array = [ 10, 10, 10, 8, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6 ];
```

I want to find the insertion index of `11`. Given that this array is sorted in *descending* order, the insertion index should be `0`.

Is there a way to compute this using lodash, without having to `reverse()` and `sort()` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `iteratee` argument of [sortedIndex()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortedIndex) to negate the item:

```
_.sortedIndex(array, 11, function(item) { return -item; });
// → 0
```

Comment: thanks, this works. I didn't think it would work since it appears that you would be comparing [-10, -10, -10, -8, -7, -6, -6, -6, -6] with 11, which wouldn't produce the right result. However, having looked at the lodash code, at the beginning, before the searching starts, there appears to also be a call made to the iteratee with the value being searched. This results in the comparison effectively being [-10... -6] with -11, reversing the sort. thanks